# How to change the layout of Object Detail Page

Tags: administration

[image]Can Anyone helpme out on this thing?

I need to change the layout of object detail page like I  need to add a new button in Custom Fields and Relationships related list of Object detail page.

Thanks
Naveen

Comment: I guess you have already created the button on Object X. Where exactly do you want to add it? On the object X page layout or on the related list on the parent object's layout?

Comment: Yup I have created the button already. I need to add on Object X Page Layout in CustomFields related list

Comment: What's this Custom Lists related list pointing to? Another child custom object?

Comment: Nope. See we will create a new CustomField using 'New' button of CustomFields RelatedList of Object Detail Page right?

Comment: There exactly i need to add one more button beside 'NEW'

Comment: Can you please provide a screenshot?

Comment: please find sc attached

Answer (score 0):

go to setup> Build> (if your object is custom)> create> Objects> (from their select your object)> page layout (click which page layout you want to change)> Buttons (from the list)> here you can see the button you have created drag and drop the button to custom button panal below.

setup> Build> (if your object is standard)> Customize> (from their select your object)> page layout (click which page layout you want to change)> Buttons (from the list)> here you can see the button you have created drag and drop the button to custom button panal below.

This may help you out.

Answer (score 0):

This is a system setup page and you don't have access to this layout. If you're looking to change the record detail layout then you need to click `Edit` on the CheckForm Layout down in the **Page Layouts** section.

Comment: Ok..thanks... I need to change this one...not detail layout

Comment: You can't change that. It's a setup page. Only Salesforce can change that page.